# Jquery overlay showing

Tags: jquery

I had  2 jsp pages with me . when I clicked one href link on the first page ..I'm redirecting to next page .but i want to stay there in the same page and want to show that page in the overlay ..any help ?
thanks

Comment: Excuse me, sir; but your overlay is showing...

Comment: jquery expose plugin might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) for overlay.

And this piece of code for not be redirected when you click on a link, in doubt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(){
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Jquery tools Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html)**
This is one of the simple to use and fearure-rich overlay and enough documentation available.